# Using jquery plugin for pagination, when load 50k records it causing entire system to freez. how to solve this?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, datatables

I need to do, when user enter number in input box and click on button to get data, then it call a java method which returns the Array list of records,now in jsp page data need to be store in table format. By jquery plugin adds pagination,searching and sorting.

The data i get from the method about 50k(records).

I followed this link to add pagination and all,
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html

The problem with this, taking about 2 to 3 mins to load the page and causing system to be hang.

From the method data is coming within faster i.e, within seconds.

If it is 500 to 1000 records it displays faster. when data increases it causing entire system to halt. It prompt  to continue or stop (js).

Errors : 
Prompt to continue or stop scripting. 
A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

Script: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js:4

And i tried without any scripts it taking max 2 to 3 mins....

Is their any feasible solution for this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: [**Server-side processing - JSP**](https://datatables.net/development/server-side/jsp)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're using client-side processing mode. Use [server-side processing mode](https://www.datatables.net/manual/data) instead to return data for the current page only.

From the [manual](https://www.datatables.net/manual/data):

> Each has its own advantages and disadvantages, but the key indicator for which mode you should select is based on the number of rows in your table. As a rule of thumb, if you are working with less than 10,000 rows use client-side processing, for greater than 100,000 rows use server-side processing. In-between is a grey area where you will need to make a decision based upon the nature of your app and the data you wish to display.

The drawback is that you would need to implement sorting, filtering and pagination in the server-side script. However there are libraries available for different languages. For example, DataTables distribution comes with PHP helper class ([ssp.class.php](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php)).